# ¿Cómo actualizar Base de datos al cerrar el navegador?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un sitio donde al momento de iniciar sesión en una tabla que tengo de usuarios, el campo estatus pasa de 0 a 1, tengo un botón donde puede cerrar sesión y este campo pasa de 1 a 0, todo bien hasta aquí. Pero al momento que el usuario cierra el navegador sin cerrar sesión desde el botón el estatus se mantiene es 1, y al querer iniciar sesión de nuevo me arroja una validación ya establecida, la validación es para que los usuarios que estén en con estatus 1, no pueda entrar con otro equipo con la misma cuenta.

Estuve investigando y encontré los eventos unload y onbeforeunload de JS, esto para que al cerrar el navegador detecte el evento y actualice la BD, me funciona pero he tenido algunos problemas de compatibilidad, estoy utilizando validaciones en estos eventos ya que al momento de recargar la pagina o dar clic en otra pestana del menú no se detecte el evento, estoy teniendo problemas con el navegador Edge.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como resolver este problema, se los agradezco por adelantado.

Comment: Lo más sano es que incluyas un factor de vigencia de la sesión en la base de datos, por ejemplo si no ves actividad los últimos 15 minutos la tomes como sesión caducada, eso te ayudaría a validar los casos en los que la computadora simplemente se desconecta de internet.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Que pasaría si el usuario cerro por accidente el navegador y abre al instante, el campo quedaría en 1, cierto?

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que al cerrar el navegador la sesión se cierre inmediatamente en la BD?

Comment: Así es,  tengo un campo de estatus, al iniciar sesión el estatus es 1 pero al cerrar el navegador el estatus sigue siendo uno, lo que quiero que es al cerrar el navegador se actualice la BD y el estatus sea 0. El campo estatus lo establecí, ya que solamente quiero que inicie sesión en un solo navegador o equipo.

Comment: Deberias reveer tu escenario... si apago mi pc (por ejemplo se queda sin bateria) no se cierra el navegador.. si se corta la luz, tampoco se cierra... si fuerzo un apagado de alguna forma, nunca vas a enterarte que se desconecto...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tambien puedo apagar js y nunca te vas a enterar que cerre la pestaña.. no se para que usas eso exactamente, pero es muy facil pasarlo por alto....

Comment: Tienen toda la razón, entonces para eso no sería nada del cliente, alguna idea de cómo resolverlo desde el servidor?